# How do I use the spread operator in this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, spread

This is on my index.js file in VSC

```
describe('appendCat(name)', function () {
  it('appends a cat to the cats array and returns a new array, leaving the cats array unchanged', function () {
    expect(appendCat("Broom")).to.have.ordered.members(["Milo", "Otis", "Garfield", "Broom"]);

    expect(cats).to.have.ordered.members(["Milo", "Otis", "Garfield"]);
  });
});
```

I am supposed to append a cat to the cats array leaving the cats array unchanged.

I have no idea how to write the function for this

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

This will spread the `cats` array, plus add a new element to it named "Broom", but the initial `cats` array will not be changed.

```
describe('appendCat(name)', function () {
  it('appends a cat to the cats array and returns a new array, leaving the cats array unchanged', function () {
    expect(appendCat("Broom")).to.have.ordered.members([...cats, "Broom"]);

    expect(cats).to.have.ordered.members(["Milo", "Otis", "Garfield"]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
[...cats, "name of cat"]
```